# FreeIPA LDAP load balancing

Tags: dns, load-balancing, freeipa

I'm setting up FreeIPA servers in my home lab. A total of 3 servers.
I also want to be able to load balance between these servers, or at least use DNS for this. I'm not installing IPAclient on my Linux servers, but rather using the LDAP connection

I came across this blog post by Dmitri Pal, where he discusses some part of Identity
Manageent and Load Balancing (See: [Identity Management and Load Balancing](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/identity-management-and-load-balancing-red-hat-enterprise-linux))

Since I'll be using AWS i'm wondering if it's beneficial to load balance the
LDAP or if we just try like Dmitri mention in the blog post to use DNS SRV records. Would
it be possible for me to so and only point one FQDN in the /etc/sssd/sssd.conf for our
hosts?

E.g
IPA servers: DNS SRV Record

```
ipa1.example.com >> ldaps_ipa.example.com
ipa2.example.com >> ldaps_ipa.example.com
ipa3.example.com >> ldaps_ipa.example.com
```

And put following in a sssd.conf file:

```
[domain/example.com]
id_provider = ldap
ldap_uri = ldaps://ipa.example.com
```